# Django - NullBooleanField won't retain False value from custom save() method

Tags: python, django, super

Newcomer to Django, so forgive me if I'm missing something obvious or doing something stupid here...

I have a Django model with a custom save() extension. Trimming the unrelated fields and methods, it looks like this:

```
class Content(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(max_length=1000)   
    image = models.URLField(blank=True, max_length=1000)
    image_type = models.NullBooleanField(default=None)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.url:
            img, img_type = image_extractor(self.url)
            print 'extractor returned: ', img_type
            print 'before set: ', self.image_type
            setattr(self, 'image', img)   
            setattr(self, 'image_type', img_type)
            print 'after set: ', self.image_type

        super(Content, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        print 'from query: ', Content.objects.get(url=self.url).image_type
```

The image_extractor function returns a url string and a boolean value representing the image type: True for images larger than a certain width, False for smaller images, or None if no suitable image was found. The problem is, when I query Content.objects and check image_type, all objects return either True or None. Hence the print statements. The images with image_type None or True work as expected, but when image_type is returned False, this is what prints:

```
extractor returned:  False
before set:  None
after set:  False
from query:  True
```

Somehow the call to super().save always reverts image_type to True if I try to set False (but not if I set None). I admit, I don't understand super() very well, but based on the documentation it seems to be necessary when extending the model function. Can anyone explain what's going on here, and how I can fix it?

Edit: I notice that I can change the value to False through the admin page and it stays False. But I still need to fix the save() method. For now, I have just replaced the boolean field with an integer field and saved values as 0 or 1, which does work. But I'd still like to know why the more appropriate field doesn't.

Comment: are you sure that `image_extractor()` is returning the right values?

Comment: Reasonably sure; this was the purpose of the print statements, to see what was being returned and where the problem occurs.

Comment: have you tried using `BooleanField(null=True, blank=True)`?

Comment: I haven't tried that, since the documentation discourages it (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null). It may be useful for troubleshooting this, though... Or I could throw out Null values rather than trying to save them and just see if True/False work with the regular BooleanField. I'll try these routes tomorrow.

Comment: That should be working - you code looks fine. You say that you've trimmed unrelated fields and methods, are you sure there's nothing funky going on there? To add to your debug, you can also `print *args, **kwargs` to ensure there's nothing being set there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since writing this question, I had moved ahead with a temporary solution of using an IntegerField to store the boolean as 0 or 1. Upon deciding to revisit the problem tonight and switching back to the NullBooleanField, suddenly everything works as intended. So it seems danodonovan was correct: the code above is correct, and unfortunately I still have no idea what was causing the error. Something else I changed while using the IntegerField must have resolved the issue. Thanks to those of you who have taken a look and offered some opinions, and I'm sorry to have wasted your time.

Answer (score 0):

the way you overload save method looks good.
I think you are not loading the good object from database.
Use the primary key will probably works better.

In your case just replace that:

```
Content.objects.get(url=self.url).image_type
```

by that:

```
Content.objects.get(pk=self.pk).image_type
```

Looks at the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#the-pk-property

Extract from the django documention:

> Once the object has been saved, you must reload the object in order to
>   access the actual value that was applied to the updated field:
>
> > > > product = Products.objects.get(pk=product.pk)
> > > >
> > > > print(product.number_sold)

Comment: Thanks. Although the url should be unique for this model, I see it is better practice to search by pk. Unfortunately, changing the search to pk still doesn't change the outcome. False is still reset to True.

Comment: Are you sure that's really unique. if you try print all objects with that url, do you get only one ? : print (Content.objects.filter(url=self.url))

Comment: I checked just to make sure, but it is unique. My intent was to only have one object per url, so in the one place in the code where new objects are created, there is a check first to see if the url exists in the database. If it does, the existing object is returned rather than creating a new one.